# Indicate whether each of the following is a valid MATLAB identifier

Tags: matlab

4ever

I know this identifier is not valid because it's start with a number which is not allow in matlab.

My question is how can I write matlab code to check whether it's valid or not?

Comment: Why do you want this? Are you after a try catch block or a better matlab IDE that catches errors better?

Comment: If what you want is for matlab to catch more errors at "compile" time then *insert rant about matlab and dynamically typed languages here*

Comment: This is a lexical error; it is independent of static vs. dynamic typing.

Comment: Its not a rant if its well thought out

Answer (score 7):

You can use `isvarname` function to check whether a given string is a valid MATLAB variable name. It will make sure it starts with a valid letter and is less than namelengthmax and is not a MATLAB keyword.

Answer (score 3):

If you have invalid identifiers MATLAB will complain and never run, so you can't create such self-reflecting code for actual identifiers.

If you want to check the validity of a certain string, just see if it adheres to MATLAB's naming rules (e.g. starts with a letter and is shorter than what `namelengthmax` returns).

More info on variable naming rules in MATLAB can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html).

Comment: Here's a usecase: I use `assignin('base', ...)` to a variable name supplied by the user as a string.